# Jupyter Notebook Repeatedly Corrupted (can save but not reload)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

In Mac Chrome, My jupyter notebooks are frequently corrupted.

Upon opening the notebook I get:

> Notebook failed to load
>   The error was:
>   ReferenceError: tbls is not defined
>   See the error console for details.

#### Work-around

In Chrome, Requires that I create a new/blank notebook and copy/paste cells into it from a Gist I continually update.

I can open and run the same 'corrupted' notebook in Safari. The problem is that the Code comments are not editable and there is a strange uneditable space between words in code comments like

```
# this       is   a      comment
```

#### Debugger

In the console debugger, I get:

```
The Console Debugger stops at the code
menubar.js:240 actions jupyter-notebook:find-and-replace does not exist, still binding it in case it will be defined later...
```

followed by...

```
Failed to load extensions: ["nbextensions/jupyter-js-widgets/extension", "nbextensions/nb_conda/models", "nbextensions/nb_conda/views", "nbextensions/nb_conda/urls"] Error: Load timeout for modules: nbextensions/jupyter-js-widgets/extension,nbextensions/nb_conda/models,nbextensions/nb_conda/views,nbextensions/nb_conda/urls
```

followed by...

```
Access to Font at 'about:blank' from origin 'http://localhost:8888' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is 
therefore not allowed access.
```

#### Installs

- Chrome 55.0.2883.9
- Mac Sierra 10.12.1 (16B2555)
- Python 3.52
- jupyter1.0.0
- jupyter_client4.3.0
- jupyter installed with conda 4.2.13

I tried opening jupyter with sudo, still won't open the notebook. Other notebooks load without issue. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling jupyter with conda

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm still dealing with this one :( Going to submit the bug to Jupyter and see if they can help me.